# Passing an HTML element to PHP via $.post() returns JavaScript object or breaks: how must I encode it?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I'm a relative JavaScript / jQuery newbie.

I'm working on exporting (to a file on the server) a dynamically-generated `<svg>` from within a dynamically-generated `<iframe>`. I've succeeded in extracting the relevant data with jQuery (i.e., I can produce an object whose contents is the `<svg>...</svg>`

Relevant snippit of my **JavaScript** parser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chart_export(svg_id) {
    var svg_data = $('iframe:first').contents().find('svg');
    svg_data = svg_data[0]; // Unwrap the [], only one element.
    console.log(svg_data); // Looks right (but perhaps it's not).
    console.log(svg_id); // Also right

    // POST svg
    $.post("chart_export.php", {'svg_post' : svg_data, 'chart_name' : svg_id}, function(data){
        alert(data); // Quick view of $_POST, no var_dump();
    });
}
</script>
```

Relevant snippit of my **PHP** parser:

```
  <?php
  $path = "module/" . "post.txt";
  $svg_data = $_POST['svg_post'];
  file_put_contents($path, $svg_data); // Same output as below
  echo json_encode($_POST); // Hack return to JS's alert() callback.
  ?>
```

for the moment, has been replaced with simply `echo json_encode($_POST);`

If I **don't unwrap** the `svg_data` object, PHP receives it as a (JavaScript?) `[object Object]` which I am unable to iterate across within PHP (such as with `$svg = $_POST['svg_data'];` which again returns `[object Object]`.

If I **do unwrap** `svg_data` within JavaScript before I post it to PHP (as in the example code above) I get `[object SVGSVGElement]`.

I caught the fix found in [**jQuery Object to string**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/jquery-object-to-string), and [Post value pairs from jQuery to php file and save data in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775024/post-value-pairs-from-jquery-to-php-file-and-save-data-in-database) but don't believe they apply to my situation (despite Cipi's comment). I also attempted `var svg_string = new String('svg_data');` to no avail (it creates a string `"[object Object]"`.

Clearly, my understanding of JavaScript data objects and jQuery selectors requires improvement.

What do I need to do, either within JavaScript/jQuery or PHP to allow me to access the raw contents of the entire `<svg>...</svg>`? I imagine it's simple and I'm missing it.

And here's the sample SVG just for good measure:

```
<svg id="chart" width="1292" height="636"><defs id="defs"><clipPath id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0"><rect x="214" y="122" width="865" height="393"></rect></clipPath></defs><g><text text-anchor="start" x="214" y="91.5" font-family="Arial" font-size="30" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">Test</text></g><g><g><text text-anchor="start" x="1127" y="139" font-family="Arial" font-size="20" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">5</text></g><rect x="1099" y="122" width="20" height="20" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#64a8d1"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="1127" y="171" font-family="Arial" font-size="20" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">4</text></g><rect x="1099" y="154" width="20" height="20" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3d9ad1"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="1127" y="203" font-family="Arial" font-size="20" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">3</text></g><rect x="1099" y="186" width="20" height="20" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#03436a"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="1127" y="235" font-family="Arial" font-size="20" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">2</text></g><rect x="1099" y="218" width="20" height="20" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#245a7a"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="1127" y="267" font-family="Arial" font-size="20" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">1</text></g><rect x="1099" y="250" width="20" height="20" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0969a2"></rect></g><g><rect x="214" y="122" width="865" height="393" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g clip-path="url(#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0)"><g><rect x="214" y="514" width="865" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="214" y="416" width="865" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="214" y="318" width="865" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="214" y="220" width="865" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="214" y="122" width="865" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect></g><g><g><rect x="270" y="319" width="177" height="195" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0969a2"></rect><rect x="269.5" y="318.5" width="178" height="196" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.3" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></rect><rect x="268.5" y="317.5" width="180" height="198" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.15" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></rect><rect x="267.5" y="316.5" width="182" height="200" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.05" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></rect></g><rect x="558" y="319" width="177" height="195" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0969a2"></rect><rect x="846" y="319" width="177" height="195" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0969a2"></rect><rect x="270" y="123" width="177" height="195" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#245a7a"></rect><rect x="558" y="123" width="177" height="195" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#245a7a"></rect><rect x="846" y="123" width="177" height="195" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#245a7a"></rect><rect x="270" y="514.5" width="177" height="0" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#03436a"></rect><rect x="558" y="514.5" width="177" height="0" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#03436a"></rect><rect x="846" y="514.5" width="177" height="0" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#03436a"></rect><rect x="270" y="514.5" width="177" height="0" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3d9ad1"></rect><rect x="558" y="514.5" width="177" height="0" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3d9ad1"></rect><rect x="846" y="514.5" width="177" height="0" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3d9ad1"></rect><rect x="270" y="514.5" width="177" height="0" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#64a8d1"></rect><rect x="558" y="514.5" width="177" height="0" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#64a8d1"></rect><rect x="846" y="514.5" width="177" height="0" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#64a8d1"></rect></g><g><rect x="214" y="514" width="865" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#333333"></rect></g></g><g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="358.5" y="538.6" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">One</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="646.5" y="538.6" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Two</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="934.5" y="538.6" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Three</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="198" y="520.1" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.0</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="198" y="422.1" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.5</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="198" y="324.1" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">1.0</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="198" y="226.1" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">1.5</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="198" y="128.1" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">2.0</text></g></g></g><g><g><path d="M438.5,303.5A1,1,0,0,1,437.5,302.5L437.5,247.5A1,1,0,0,1,438.5,246.5L488.5,246.5A1,1,0,0,1,489.5,247.5L489.5,302.5A1,1,0,0,1,488.5,303.5L479.5,303.5L447.5,319.5L463.5,303.5Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.4" fill="#cccccc" transform="translate(2, 2)"></path><path d="M438.5,303.5A1,1,0,0,1,437.5,302.5L437.5,247.5A1,1,0,0,1,438.5,246.5L488.5,246.5A1,1,0,0,1,489.5,247.5L489.5,302.5A1,1,0,0,1,488.5,303.5L479.5,303.5L447.5,319.5L463.5,303.5Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.6" fill="#cccccc" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path d="M438.5,303.5A1,1,0,0,1,437.5,302.5L437.5,247.5A1,1,0,0,1,438.5,246.5L488.5,246.5A1,1,0,0,1,489.5,247.5L489.5,302.5A1,1,0,0,1,488.5,303.5L479.5,303.5L447.5,319.5L463.5,303.5Z" stroke="#cccccc" stroke-width="1" fill="#ffffff" transform="translate(0, 0)"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="447" y="269.6" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">One</text><text text-anchor="start" x="447" y="290.6" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">1:</text><text text-anchor="start" x="465" y="290.6" font-family="Arial" font-size="16" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">1</text></g></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is about not getting the real HTML structure of the `<svg/>`  element, that's the reason why you got `[object SVGSVGElement]` and `[object SVGSVGElement]` as representation strings of it. You should do something like

```
$("<div/>").html(svg_data).html()
```

to get a string with the HTML contents of the element. I am not sure whether there another way to do it, but I think this will do fine.

Comment: That did it! I knew I wasn't properly acquiring the HTML from the object; I just didn't know how to get to it. For future reference, what does the initial `$("<div/>")` do: create a new DOM element and stick my `svg_data_object`'s jQuery selector into it, then grab the HTML from it? And why the trailing `/`?

Comment: @msanford, `<div/>` is a shorthand for `<div></div>` which both are empty elements. Then add your `<svg>...</svg>` as a content and request the contents of it as a string. Basically `.html()` will get the HTML of the contents of the element, which is the reason I am enclosing it before to get the HTML of the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript's escape function to make it portable. I have a personal preference for json encoding when communicating between javascript and PHP.

Here's the reference for escape:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

and this one's for json encoding:

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately, escaping the string doesn't work. I assume because JavaScript's `svg_data` variable is an object, I simply get an escaped version of its name: `%5Bobject%20Object%5D` or `%5Bobject%20SVGSVGElement%5D` (depending on whether I choose `svg_chart_obj` or `svg_chart_obj[0]` respectively). When I attempted to implement `array2json()`, I actually get a *stack overflow* ;) (`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`).

Comment: You could try serialize as well